# How to not specify a local username in an executable path in Windows

Tags: windows, path

I manage an Internet cafe and use a program called GGLeap which allows customers to operate an interface to execute applications from a local path, to ultimately avoid any interaction with our desktops. However, I can only set one executable path per program.

The computers have serialized local usernames for easy network identification (my first computer would named be G1, my second computer would be named G2, and so forth).

Certain programs automatically install on local paths underneath the user folder.

For example, in G1 and G2 this would be

```
C:\Users\G1\myprogramlauncher.exe
C:\Users\G2\myprogramlauncher.exe
```

As I can only specify one path, I currently can not use programs located underneath user folders and seek a method to bypass or omit the local username of a computer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I’m confused but interested so I’ll try to help...

I looked at the applications installation video and noticed on their example. They used a virtual machine that had the applications ggleap will allow access to installed in the programs directory.  I think may need to globally install these programs on each computer for all users including the client ggleap application. You then will be restricting the permissions to each computer by adding in each user for each computer. 
The global installation for all users may be required for flexibility.

For example...
You have a special event every Monday. You could create a user account for each computer on Monday’s.  You switch users on each computer, now each computer is capable of seeing a whole new array of available applications to use. This way instead of changing the current users settings for each computer every single Monday, then undo what you did on Tuesday you just have to set it up once and switch users.

Also the ability to log into a user account that’s located on a different computer on the same network is possible. It is usually disabled by default. But it could be a great way to for you to test out the computers configuration ect.